# How to make docker service start on my system reboot automatically?

Tags: docker, containers

I have installed docker and have a running container. I know that when we give restart-always the docker container restarts. But how do we make the docker service restart automatically on system reboot ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Docker automatically is a service that starts when the system restarts. So, I didn't need to create a new file in init.d. Giving **restart-always** to the docker container while it's being started allowed me to restart a docker service on system restart without any problems.